# Change background color of a div with a button inside

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to change the background color of a button when it has focus. The background color is correct but the image disappears when focussed. I'm looking for a solution using pure CSS.

This is my code

```css
    #templatebtn {
        background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo1vDaH0IexRj_MOvI7AMzSGt79t_4vvVNccccLZz9FkP2n4wU);
        height: 94px;
        width: 140px;
        position: absolute;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: none;
        background-position: 50px;
    }

    #tcolor {
        background-color: #d0cece;height: 93px;
        width: 140px;
    }

    #templatebtn:hover, #templatebtn:focus {
        background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo1vDaH0IexRj_MOvI7AMzSGt79t_4vvVNccccLZz9FkP2n4wU);
        height: 94px;
        width: 140px;
        position: absolute;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;   
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%); height: 94px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="tcolor"><button id="templatebtn"></button></div>
```

Comment: For the love of all things programming, please format your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you were looking for.

```css
#templatebtn {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo1vDaH0IexRj_MOvI7AMzSGt79t_4vvVNccccLZz9FkP2n4wU);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 140px;
    height: 94px;
}

#tcolor{
    background-color: #d0cece;
}

#templatebtn:hover,
#templatebtn:focus {
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo1vDaH0IexRj_MOvI7AMzSGt79t_4vvVNccccLZz9FkP2n4wU), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
```

```html
<div id="tcolor"><button id="templatebtn"></button></div>
```

Comment: Fairly sure the OP is trying to change the div background, not the button. Which I'm pretty sure isn't possible with CSS being cascading and all

Comment: @DylanB perhaps I misread the question a bit, but at the same time, the last thing they mention is, "The background color is correct but the image disappears when focussed." Based on that is where I gave an answer.

Comment: Oh believe me, reading the question was an emotionally exhaustive exercise but I think the question is asking how to change the parent background from the childs' focus. I could be wrong...

Comment: Yes , is just exactly what i want to do.

Comment: @alsuelo what is exactly what you're trying to do? RhapXs' answer or my interpretation?

Comment: Excellent, you need to rephrase your question then.

Answer (score 0):

## templatebtn {

```
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo1vDaH0IexRj_MOvI7AMzSGt79t_4vvVNccccLZz9FkP2n4wU);
    height: 94px;
    width: 140px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: 50px;
}

#tcolor {
    background-color: #d0cece;height: 93px;
    width: 140px;
}

#templatebtn:hover, #templatebtn:focus {
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo1vDaH0IexRj_MOvI7AMzSGt79t_4vvVNccccLZz9FkP2n4wU);
    height: 94px;
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%); height: 94px;
```

}